# Sessions for Multiple Logins account

Tags: php, security, authentication

How does Sessions structure should look like for multiple logins?

There will be three parts of logins on my website.

/ (customer area)

/admin/ (backend/admin area)

/control-panel/ (control panel area)

You can not use same account to access all three.

I came up with like this:

```
$_SESSION['login']['frontend'] = array(
    'user_id' => 123,
    'is_logged' => true
        );


$_SESSION['login']['backend'] = array(
    'user_id' => 999,
    'is_logged' => true
        );
```

Is this correct or what is alternative solution?

Comment: You can also use different folders for different sessions (if you have login happening at different urls for different types of users). You use session_save_path for that - in headers for those urls you specify different session folders like session_save_path('../../admin_sessions'). Not sure which way is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look's perfectly fine to me. :)